# How to display text file in a text view for Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstextview

The code below opens a file open dialog box and enables the user to browse for and select a file. Rather than displaying in the output box, how would one output the text from the file into the text view box in storyboard within Xcode?

```
-(IBAction)openButton:(id)sender {
    // Create the File Open Dialog class.
    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    // Enable the selection of files in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];

    // Multiple files not allowed
    [openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];

    // Can't select a directory
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];

    // Display the dialog. If the OK button was pressed,
    // process the files.
    if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSModalResponseOK )
    {
        // Once a file has been opened and assigned a file handle, the contents of that file may be read from the current offset position. The readDataOfLength method reads a specified number of bytes of data from the file starting at the current offset. For example, the following code reads 5 bytes of data from offset 10 in a file. The data read is returned encapsulated in an NSData object.


        NSFileHandle *file;
        NSData *databuffer;

        NSURL *selection = openDlg.URLs[0];
        NSString *path = [[selection path]stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath];

        file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:(@"%@", path)];

        if (file == nil)
            NSLog(@"Failed to open file");

        databuffer = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

        [file closeFile];
        NSString* newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[databuffer bytes]];

        NSLog(@"%@", newStr);
    }
}
```

And there here's the IBOutlet portion of the code

```
@property (noatomic, readwrite, weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *sourceLabel;
-(IBAction) openButton:(id)sender;
```

I'm not sure what else to do to connect the outlet to the textview to display the text from the file

Comment: Does textView.text = newStr; not work?

Comment: @Alex Xcode says textview is undeclared? So i'm assuming the text area has a variable name but not sure how to check that.

Comment: Did you hook one up in the storyboard or have you created one in code? Is it on the screen and visible?

Comment: I did on storyboard. It is on the screen and visible.

Comment: You have to connect it to your class with an IBOutlet, you can access it from there

Comment: @Alex  Okay, I edited my original question, any help?